# How to auto hide multiple alerts one by one. first in - first out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, typescript

I have a notification area in a webpage, which can contain multiple bootstrap alerts.

```
<div class='notification-area> </div>
```

I am trying to display multiple alerts as they come,  and make the oldest ones auto close after 5 seconds, first one first out.

[image: example]

**Here's what I have so far. note: it closes everything all at once.**

```
showNotification(header: string, text: string, alertAttribute: string) {
            var notificationBoxID: string = "notificationBox" + $('.notification-area').children().length;


       //Appends this html into the notification-area class
        $('.notification-area').append(
            '<section id="' + notificationBoxID + '" class="alert  alert- dismissible" role="alert">' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"  aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
            '<p style ="font-weight: bold;" class="notification-message-header"></p>' +
            '<p class="notification-message-body"></p>' +

            '</section>'
            );

        // Selects the children  of the notificationBoxId section.
        var notificationSel = '#' + notificationBoxID;

        //set the notification: header, body and css style dynamically
        $(notificationSel + ' > .notification-message-header').text(header);
        $(notificationSel + ' > .notification-message-body').text(text);
        $(notificationSel).addClass(alertAttribute);

     // Auto hides alerts, oldest first
        $(".alert").show(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 1).slideUp(500, () => {

                    $(notificationBoxID).hide();
                })
            }, 5000)
        });
```

Anyone knows how I can approach this issue? I have tried everything. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) has timeouts, so they are handled fifo.

```
<script src="toastr.js"></script>

  var options = {
    "preventDuplicates": true,
    "timeOut": 5000
  };
  toastr.options = options;
  toastr.warning('this is the message, 'Warning:');
```

Comment: Thanks! That could be useful. I actually want multiple alerts to be shown at once. But the oldest ones will disappear after a time.

Comment: Oh this shows multiple alerts at a time :) They just pile up in the alert area (in my app that's top right). Maybe the screen area is configurable. Anyway, it you call success, info, warning or error, it just adds the new notification below any existing ones (or above, if you set that property).